# tikz-cd package on MacTex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, mactex

I just updated by TeXShop using TeX Live utility yesterday, but I still get this error. All I am doing is the standard routine

```
\[\begin{tikzcd}  
0 \arrow[hookrightarrow]{r}   
  & A\arrow[hookrightarrow]{r}{\varphi}\arrow[hookrightarrow]{d}{\eta_1}   
  & B\arrow{r}{\psi}\arrow{d}{\eta_2}   
  & C\arrow{r}\arrow{d}{\eta_3}   
  & 0 \\  
0 \arrow[hookrightarrow]{r}   
  & A'\arrow[hookrightarrow]{r}[swap]{\varphi'}   
  & B'\arrow{r}[swap]{\psi'}   
  & C'\arrow{r}  
  & 0   
\end{tikzcd}\]
```

but get this error and just cannot render.

> [image]

I also specifically updated `tikz-cd` package so I don't know why it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do a full update with TeX Live Utility; in particular, update the `pgf` package.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the console message, it seems that this new version of `tikz-cd` requires `pgf` v. 3.0, and it appears you still have version 2.10 installed. Maybe you should update the whole `pgf` package to version 3.0 and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install pgf 3.0, which is [available on CTAN](http://latex-community.org/home/news/84-news-latex-graphics-figures-tables/491-tikz-pgf-30) since some days. The `quotes` library belongs to it.